# Type cannot implement 'X' as it has a non-exported method and is defined in a different package

Tags: go, grpc

I have this code:

```
s := grpc.NewServer()
pb.RegisterMessageServiceServer(s, &messageServer{})
```

I have this error:

> Cannot use '&messageServer{}' (type *messageServer) as the type
> MessageServiceServer Type cannot implement 'MessageServiceServer' as
> it has a non-exported method and is defined in a different package

My messageServer struct looks like:

```
type messageServer struct{}

func (s *messageServer) mustEmbedUnimplementedMessageServiceServer() {
    //TODO implement me
    panic("implement me")
}

func (s *messageServer) MustEmbedUnimplementedMessageServiceServer() {
    //TODO implement me
    panic("implement me")
}

func (s *messageServer) SendMessage(ctx context.Context, msg *pb.Message) (*pb.Response, error) {
    // Write the message to Kafka
    producer, err := sarama.NewSyncProducer([]string{kafkaBroker}, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error creating Kafka producer: %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    defer producer.Close()

    kafkaMsg := &sarama.ProducerMessage{
        Topic: kafkaTopic,
        Value: sarama.StringEncoder(msg.Content),
    }

    _, _, err = producer.SendMessage(kafkaMsg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to send message to Kafka: %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return &pb.Response{Message: "Message sent to Kafka"}, nil
}
```

the error is on this line:

```
pb.RegisterMessageServiceServer(s, &messageServer{}) // here
```

no idea what's happening :(

Comment: Is `messageServer` in the same package as `MessageServiceServer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not supposed to provide an implementation of `mustEmbedUnimplementedMessageServiceServer()`. You're supposed to make your server struct embed `UnimplementedMessageServiceServer`. The member is named that to tell you that. The interface also has a doc comment that says

> All implementations must embed UnimplementedMessageServiceServer for forward compatibility.

The idea is that some day, the gRPC devs might add a new method to the interface for servers. If they do, they will also add a new method to the `unimplemented` types that returns a "method Blah not implemented" error. Since you're forced to embed their `unimplemented` type in your server type, you will inherit that method, and get a default implementation that throws an error, instead of having your code suddenly start failing typechecks because your server type is missing the new method.